# Oracledb in Node.js

Tags: node.js, oracle, npm, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I am trying to install a package:
npm install oracledb

```
Error Message:
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "db-oracle"
npm ERR! node v4.1.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND my-proxy.example.com my-proxy.example.com:80
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dell\npm-debug.log
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: Yes I am using a proxy. "my-proxy.example.com my-proxy.example.com:80"

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not an actual proxy server.

Comment: I followed this steps. https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#instwin

Comment: Got the error. Thank you.

Comment: i have same problem :(